# Xpath: getting data by comparing attributes

Tags: xpath

I need to assign an XPath expression to а reference tag which will generate automated text near my reference. The generated text should be taken from the title of the target element(figure).

This is how it looks.
Reference construction(could be located anywhere)

```
<internalRef internalRefId="fig1"></internalRef>
```

figure construction(may be anywhere)

```
    <figure id="fig1">
<title>The TEXT I TRY TO GET
</title>
...
</graphic>
</figure>
```

I guess i should take the "title in figure" tag content  if the figure's id attribute matches the link's target attribute.
One of my fail expression variants that prints nothing

```
//figure[self/@internalRefId=@id]/title
```

Thanks for ideas...

Answer (score 1):

You're searching for `@internalRefId` attributes inside some non-existent `<self/>` element. Use you write the `<internalRef/>` element "could be located anywhere", this should be fine:

```
//figure[//@internalRefId=@id]/title
```

This will return all title elements for figures that have an `@id` equal to any `@internalRefId` attribute anywhere in the document.

Comment: Yes I have the generated text in my links now. But I got all the figure titles for each link. But I need only one figure's title - the target of the link.

**PS** to make it clear, im working with stylesheet editor. It allows to insert custom XPATH expressions when needed. So the expression we are trying to make is like a template/style for any InternalRef element in the document.
So I believe I shall have something else instead of '//@internalRefId', something which poits to nearest InternalRef, as i'm modifying the expression related to design of this tag..

Comment: So you've got exactly one `<internalRef/>` element in your document, or you have any XPath expression that queries a special one for which you want to retrieve the `<figure/>`?

Comment: No I may have lots of IternalRefs. I'm making an SGML(FOSI) style for processing XML documents. The style allows to use XPATH expressions for counters, automatic text etc.
The style is universal. It should generate "See figure %Figure title%" with every link to the figure which is met by the style processor. 
When style meets InternalRef it adds '<AddTextAfter>See figure.  <_gte:XPathString expr="//figure[//@internalRefId=@id]/title"
/> </AddTextAfter>'

Comment: Now I somewhat get what you want to do. You try to look up the figure for one special internalRef. You will need some way to pass the attribute value into the XPath expression. What is the context item for XPath expressions? What XPath version is supported? Can you somehow pass variables?

Comment: I guess the XPATH is 1.0. I can edit style via Notepad and I see the system generates XSL variables, so I can create my own I guess. But I don't know if XSL variables are useful with custom XPATH expression. 
The context for XPATH expression is InternalRef element it seems to me:

<xsl:variable name="current" select="."/>
<Element name="internalRef" style="link">
...some conditions and font formatting...
<GeneratedText><AddTextAfter>See figure. <_gte:XPathString expr="//figure[//@internalRefId=@id]/title" /> </AddTextAfter></GeneratedText>
....
</Element>`

Comment: I can easily get the contents of the targetted figures if figure Id matches InternalRefId even without XPATH injections just by using FOSI functionality. But getting Figure contents brings also all the child tags like graphics, legend and so on... Thats why i decided to put custom expression. Don't know if it was a good idea.